# php scripts gets a node value , if it equals specified value ; changes a node value has its same parent node

Tags: php, xml, tags, simplexml, nodes

just like the title I need help in a php script gets "name" node value , if it equals specified given value ; changes "rate" node value has its same "person" parent node.
the xml file 'rate.xml' like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user>
<person>
<name>jessy</name> 
<rate>2</rate>
</person>
<person>
<name>mice</name>
<rate>5</rate>
</person>
</user>
```

the script will be similar to this

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$like = $_POST['like'];

$doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents ('rate.xml'));

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$nlist = $xpath->query("//user/person/rate");

$node = $nlist->item(0);

$newval = trim($node->nodeValue)-1;

$node->nodeValue = $newval;

file_put_contents ('rate.xml', $doc->saveXML());


?>
```

My missing part is how to type "if" condition checks if name equals the name I passed to "POST" and how to limit the change to the "rate" node that comes after this "name" node with the "POST['name']" value.
implementation will be a great help 
Kind regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this

```
$name = "jessy";
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user>
<person>
<name>jessy</name> 
<rate>2</rate>
</person>
<person>
<name>mice</name>
<rate>5</rate>
</person>
</user>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
for($i = 0; $i < count($xml->person); $i ++) {
    if ($xml->person[$i]->name == $name) {
        $xml->person[$i]->rate = $xml->person[$i]->rate - 1;
    }
}
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user>
    <person>
        <name>jessy</name>
        <rate>1</rate>    <----- Modified rate for jessy
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>mice</name>
        <rate>5</rate>
    </person>
</user>
```