# Filter hours in rss feed parse php

Tags: php, rss

I have a php file that gets rss feeds from other pages and implement them on my own page... The question is how can i filter out rss feeds by hours?

```
 <?php
     $html = "";
     $url = "http:www.yoursite.com/rss";
     $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
     for($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++){
         $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
         $link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
         $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
         $pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;
         $pubDate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d" "%H:%M:%S", strtotime($pubDate));
         //%H shows the pubDate Hour

         $html .= "<h3>$title</h3>";
         $html .= "$description";
         $html .= "<br /><a href='$link'>Weiterlesen</a>";
         $html .= "<br /><br />$pubDate";
    }
    echo $html;
?>
```

The goal is like having all feed that was published on 10pm for example!

Answer (score 0):

can you put the xml objects into an array and see if the value exists.

```
$var = array ('1pm','2pm','10pm')

if (in_array('10pm', $var, true)) {

echo 'this is 10pm';

}
```

Comment: i'm not using xml files or save them in db... my php code is inside html... so it just show me the last post of the newsletter

Comment: right, but when you copy and paste http:www.yoursite.com/rss into a browser window what is it returning?   
 in your case, you're pulling all the info from the rss feed url (which is xml or json) with these variables: 
         

         $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
         $link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
        etc...

what you want to do is put these variables into an array and then see if a specific value exists in that array.

Comment: here's a post that might help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934373/php-scripts-gets-a-node-value-if-it-equals-specified-value-changes-a-node-va

Comment: i'm not so good in programming... sorry :(... I have also a problem with putting the %H in $pubDate in an array...